# Firebase admin sdk java listener for realtime databse

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement the firebase admin SDK in Kotlin. I want to have a listener in the realtime database to listen update from this database.
My problem is when I run the main function, the run begin and then finish the process immediately without listen update in realtime database.

Ther is my code :

```
fun main() {
    val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("path/to/key.json")
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("URLDATABASE")
        .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("/waitingList")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            print("TEST")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            println("The read failed: " + databaseError.code)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Since addValueEventListener is asynchronous and returns immediately, your main function is also going to return immediately before any callback is invoked.  You might have to do something to prevent main from returning right away.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! But do you have any idea how to achieve this ? I am stuck with this since 3 days :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When is your program suppose to stop ? You could either:
1 -> launch it in a new coroutine:

```
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch a new coroutine in background and continue

        val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("path/to/key.json")
        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("URLDATABASE")
            .build()

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference("/waitingList")
        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                print("TEST")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                println("The read failed: " + databaseError.code)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

2 -> add a while sleep at the end:

```
fun main() {

    val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("path/to/key.json")
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("URLDATABASE")
        .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("/waitingList")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            print("TEST")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            println("The read failed: " + databaseError.code)
        }
    })

    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!! This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks